# The module structure of the vector field over a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, modules, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension m and $X:M \rightarrow TM$ a smooth vectorial field. The set of all vectorial fields,( $\mathcal{X}(M)$,+,.) forms a $C^{\infty}(M)$ module.

Is this module free?

Also, locally by chosing a local chart, I can prove that this module is finite generated. But is it globally finite generated?

Comment: [Not necessarily free](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4052994/568204) (or see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3088705/568204)), but [is finitely generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/748497/568204).

Comment: If $M$ is compact, by Swan's theorem the module of vector fields is projective. This is slightly weaker than saying that it is free.